# Access-Control-Allow-Origin | Fetch JS

Tags: javascript, fetch

I find myself facing a problem ...
Indeed, I would like to run this code (js):

```js
fetch('https://j0ke.xyz/free/api/garsvsfilles')
     .then(res => { return res.json() })
     .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
})
```

But, I am getting several errors in the browser console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AarVs.png

If anyone could help me solve this problem, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Hey the CORS error is a pretty weird thing, which prevents you to fetch from a browser to another ip address, you need to add cors on your backend server, please share the backend code with us, so we can improve it to use cors :)

Comment: What's so weird about it??

Comment: with weird i meant, that it is pretty hard to understand, bc of some things :)

Comment: I'm not me codes the back-end

Comment: @Yaniv - then you won't be able to fix this - you'll need to use your own server to make the request as a proxy to your web page - the duplicate has all the information you need to fix

Comment: Hmm, than there is no other way, than contacting the owner of the api, to update cors, but ther may be a reason why he dont want it, try to get in contact with them i guess

Comment: Or use your own server to make the request as I suggested